# How to remove the recipes from the Node for Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have run sudo chef-client on the node, and it have the files inside the node. But now I would like to remove the package from the node. If I remove the recipie in run_list from chef-server, it will not remove from the nodes.

please advise me what is the best way to have remove the package on nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every resource in Chef has one or more actions. Usually the default action is something along the lines of `install` or `create`, but they generally offer the reverse as well. In this case you would want to make a new recipe (or change the existing one) with a resource like:

```
package 'foo' do
  action :remove
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be an uninstall recipe but that feels like a bit of an anti-pattern really because we are only going to want to uninstall once really aren't we so having it run everytime would be a bit weird.

Is this a repeatable server definition that you may want to spin other copies of? If so I would say a manual remove may be cleanest and let your role definition or run list definition be consistent across machines.

Another option if you really want to code it up and have it in chef is in your default recipe have an attribute that indicates if it should be 'enabled' or 'installed'

```
if node['your_package']['enabled'].eql?("false")
   uninstall_it_if_installed()
else
   install_it_if_missing()
end
```

Again I'm not sure that's really the cleanest or what Chef is necessarily intended to do but it may get you where you want to go.

The other option is to blow away the box and start it again using the run list definition you desire saved as a role "myServerType". I think on paper that's the cleanest solution but of course there can be lots of reasons that doesn't suit